# Проблема с микроразметкой организации (hcard) в Гугл-валидаторе

Tags: микроразметка, google-console

Пытаюсь реализовать микроразметку организации (hcard) так, чтобы и Гугл и Яндекс ее воспринимали без ошибок. С Яндексом все ок, но вот Гугл-валидатор микроразметки выдает предупреждение, мол укажите поле pricerange - но ведь оно уже указано. И в валидаторе даже прописано... Вот скриншот
[image: Инструмент проверки структурированных данных]

А вот сам код:

```html
<div class="vcard">
  <a class="fn org url" href="http://www.commerce.net/">CommerceNet</a>
  <img class="logo-ft photo" src="images/logo-footer.png" alt="Company Logo">
  <div class="adr">
    <span class="type">Work</span>:
    <div class="street-address">169 University Avenue</div>
    <span class="locality">Palo Alto</span>,  
    <abbr class="region" title="California">CA</abbr>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="postal-code">94301</span>
    <div class="country-name">USA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tel">
   <span class="type">Work</span> +1-650-289-4040
  </div>
   <div>Pricerange: 
   <span class="pricerange">from $10 to $20</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Заранее спасибо всем, кто поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить полю класс `fn pricerange` и ошибка пропадёт.

```html
<span class="fn pricerange">from $10 to $20</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...Гугл-валидатор микроразметки выдает предупреждение...

Это рекомендация для необязательного свойства, имеющего много разных вариантов заполнения.